# Do I fulfill the mitzvah of mishloach manot by giving two dog biscuits to my dog?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Esther 9:19 says:

ומשלוח מנות איש לרעהו

A person should give mishlo'ach manot each person to his friend. They say that a dog is "man's best friend". Well, my dog, Charvonah, is really my best friend. He's very faithful! (and gorgeous, too, I should add. Know any dogs that need a shidduch??) Can I fulfill the mitzvah of mishloach manot by giving him 2 dog biscuits?

BTW - the biscuits are ראוי לאכילת כלב

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

No, two dog biscuits are not two different foods. You should instead give him:

- one biscuit and one can of Alpo
- alternatively, one biscuit and one bone left from a steak

Since I assume you are also his friend, I would like to help *him* send *you* a mishlo'ach manot.  If you provide your address, I would be happy to send you a dog biscuit and can of Alpo for your own enjoyment (bli neder, since I'm not sure I can find one with a good hescher).

**May you and your pooch have a joyous Purim and be written this year in the book of drunkenness!**

Comment: Two different foods? ....some (admittedly, not all) hold that you can do mishloach manos with one piece of club bread, that's big enough for two sandwiches.

Comment: Nobody ever said it has to be two different foods.

Comment: @user6591  I am used to you being right, but Wikipedia says, "According to the halakha, every Jew over the age of Bar and Bat Mitzvah should send a food gift consisting of two different types of food to at least one recipient." they quote 
Rabbi Elozor Barclay and Rabbi Yitzchok Jaeger as their source at http://www.aish.com/h/pur/m/48968806.html "No, the two food items must be different. However it is not necessary for the items to require two different blessings. For example, one may send two different cakes or two fruits."

Comment: @Mike Shulchan Aruch 695 4 says as example 'two manos of meat'. Admittedly, the Aruch Hashulchan there 14, says it must be two types of manos, but two PIECES of one type doesn't work, his logic is would we say if someone cuts one piece into two, should it work? But note, he argues on the reading of the Rambam which the Mechaber is quoting. But even the aruch hashulchan has limits to his logic. Perhaps he would agree two whole cookies (or dog biscuits!:) would be fine.

Comment: @Mike I think that people have taken his words a bit out of context. If that is the source for the common claim. But again even he is not in accordance with the simple reading of the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: But +1 because you do have a source for the position stated.